# Foam Tile Material

Tags: materials

I'm trying to create a grid of foam tiles for a project I am working on. The texture has some imperfections on it and I'm just trying to figure out the best way to go about creating this texture. I modeled the actual tile already so the material doesn't have to include the puzzle pattern luckily.

Here is what I am trying to create:
[image: foam tiles]

Here is what I have tried so far. My attempts at making this included plugging in a surface imperfections map into the roughness of the material but it did not achieve the effect I was going for:

[image: attempt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe first look for a texture that will mimic the rubber surface. Use it as a factor between 2 variations of the same color, one a bit brighter and glossier than the other, but keep it rather matte. At the end plug a *Subsurface Scattering* to increase the rubber feeling.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are a genius, thank you.